# AX R3 Enterprise Portal added new field to table, and form but field value is not persisting to table

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have added a new field of type TransDate to HRMAbsenceRequest table, then I updated the respected EP page (HcmEPAbsenceRequestEdit in visual studio 2013. The Dataset is updated and showing the new field in field groups. So I just add the new field in group, refresh AOD, data, and dictionary. Form is updated and showing new field. Filled the form with valid values and submit it. But When I checked the table (using SQL Server Management Studio) the record is inserted but new field is empty (no values). I have already tried syncing table, restart AX, Dynamics Service, and SQL Server service. But it's not working for me at the moment.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might try is checking the parm method in the AX class.

Rather than

```
public fieldType parmfieldName(fieldType _fieldName = fieldName) 
{
    fieldName = _fieldName;

    return fieldName;
}
```

This is how it should be defined for the data to be saved to the table

```
public fieldType parmfieldName(fieldType _fieldName = fieldName) 
{
    if (!prmisdefault(_fieldName))
    {
        this.setField(fieldnum(Table, FieldName), _fieldName);
    }

    return Table.fieldName; 
}
```